# Elasticsearch querying hourly range doesn't work properly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I was looking for a way to get specific data that has happened between midnight and 4AM. A quick google search gave me this query:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['InitiationTimestamp'].value.hourOfDay >= params.startHour && doc['InitiationTimestamp'].value.hourOfDay <= params.endHour",
              "params": {
                "startHour": 0,
                "endHour": 4
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When searching with start time 0, and end time 4, it shows data from 1am until 4am, completely missing midnight.
And when I change endTime from 4 to 2 or 1, it instead shows data until 3 am. 
This is very confusing and doesn't make any sense. Does anyone know what is going on here?

This is how a value of InitiationTimestamp looks like: `November 27th 2019, 02:58:11.000`

This is the mapping for ConnectedToAgent timestamp. I changed it to this one since I needed to know when the call actually got connected to the agent.

```
"ctr-logs-2019-11-27-00" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "AmznConnect" : {
          "Agent" : {
           "properties" : {
            ...
            "ConnectedToAgentTimestamp" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              ...
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `InitiationTimestamp` field ?

Comment: Hey @Val thanks for your input, how would I do that?

Comment: Run `GET your-index-name` and update your question with the results

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, it's `"type" : "date"`

Comment: Ok, but what format?

Comment: I removed some properties that are not needed for this example, here's how the response looks: updated the question

Comment: Ok, so you have not specified any [format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), and your dates don't match the default format. You need to either change the way to store your date to match the default format or specify your custom format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Val, I'll take a look at this.